# Routing problem finding shortest route to line

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, linear-referencing

inspiration on how to solve this problem.
(Ascii art, I don't have points to insert picture)

I need to find Z

Z = Shortest route from X Using Road (no point exists here)

O = The points that makes the line

X = Start point

Y = Closest point on line (Can't be used)

The problem right now is:
The nearest point (Y) from X will give a long route.

Route from X to Points (O) on line also returns a long route.

Any idea on how I can find Z ??

```
    O(Point)
    | ||
Line| ||       O2----------O2 (closer line but no road to this line so this can't be used)
    | ||
    | ||
    |Y||         X (Start point)
    | ||         ||
    | ||    ||   ||Road
    | ||    ||   ||
    | ||    ||   ||
    |Z||----||----Road
    | ||    ||
    | ||    ||------------- Road
    | ||
    | ||Road
    | ||
    | ||
    O (Point)
```

Is there anyway I can take the line and add more points to it on every 5 meters? So the Line would look like O-O-O-O-O-O instead of O---------O

Setup:
I have a postgres 9.3 with postgis 2
The database has all X (points)
All Lines (linestring)
And all roads (Export from openstreet)

(can't get pgrouting to work right now)
And a local osrm server running.

Comment: I had a similar problem and instead of creating "psuedo nodes", I ended up using a function that would calculate the portions (whole or partial) reachable along the edges of the network. Have a look at this thread - http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154826/return-nodes-along-portions-of-edges-with-pgrouting

Comment: For adding more points to linestrings, see my answer here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/88199/15459!

Comment: You say that no point exists at Z. But if there is no node there, then there's no route from X to either end of the O-O edge. Do you just need to add nodes at line intersections?

Answer (score 1):

To add more points on the line use `ST_Segmentize`.

The easiest solution using pgRouting would be calculating shortest part from X to middle of O and then all alternate paths where the distance is within `shortest path length + half of the length of line o` (which can be done by disabling the last edge used in the route).