# How can I transform polylines into points every n metres in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, point, line

Question in pretty much the same as [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69949/add-points-for-every-100-m-at-polyline-qgis-mapinfo), but I need to use PostGIS.

I have a number of polylines, and want to trasform them into points every n metres along these lines.

**edit:**
Thanks a lot to Stefan. My final query was a bit different, probably due to older version of PostGIS (1.5), but in the end I got what was needed. Points were combined into a heatmap of roads density.
[image]

Comment: ST_LocateAlong: http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_LocateAlong.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This query should do the trick:

```
WITH line AS 
    (SELECT
        your_polylinestring_id,
        (ST_Dump(geom)).geom AS geom
    FROM your_polylinestring_table),
linemeasure AS
    (SELECT
        ST_AddMeasure(line.geom, 0, ST_Length(line.geom)) AS linem,
        generate_series(0, ST_Length(line.geom)::int, 10) AS i
    FROM line),
geometries AS (
    SELECT
        i,
        (ST_Dump(ST_GeometryN(ST_LocateAlong(linem, i), 1))).geom AS geom 
    FROM linemeasure)

SELECT
    i,
    ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(ST_X(geom), ST_Y(geom)), 31468) AS geom
FROM geometries
```

1. At first you select the distinct linestrings from your polylinestring column with `ST_Dump`
2. Then you have to define the measure elements with `ST_AddMeasure`, starting with 0 (begin of the linestring) and the end of the linestring (same as the length of the linestring). `Generate_series` creates a series over the this measurement by the step of 10. Here you can define `"n metres"` (in this example 10 meters). The `i` value begins anew for every linestring.
3. With `ST_LocateAlong` and `ST_GeometryN` you create a multidimensional point geometry.
4. Finally you have to extract the X and Y values of this geometry and create a point from it.

The result could look like this:
[image]

**EDIT**

To be fair, I want to add this information:
The idea and the query in this answer is extracted from a query that I'm using to create drape lines from DEMs in PostGIS. The excellent implementation of this is explained in this [article](http://blog.mathieu-leplatre.info/drape-lines-on-a-dem-with-postgis.html) from Mathieu Leplatre.

Comment: Can you clarify, b/c I'm not familiar with these SQL constructs: where `WITH line AS` is used? I don't see 'line' elsewhere.

Comment: @culebrón The `WITH Query` provides the use of temporary tables for larger queries. Here are some information: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html. `line` is used in the next subquery `linemeasure`. The selected data in this subquery is based on the selections made in the `line` subquery. They are build upon one another. Hope that helped!

Comment: In PostGIS older than 2.0 the function is `st_locate_along_measure`.