# Point sampling along a pole-wrapping coastline with PostGIS

Tags: postgis, point, spherical-geometry, antarctica

I am working on a task that requires me to get sample points every 1000 km along coastlines, and have run into a problem with Antarctica. From what I can tell, it seems to be an issue with the use of *geometry* in the functions, when really I think *geography* should be used for this operation.

Using the function from [this very similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/88196/how-can-i-transform-polylines-into-points-every-n-metres-in-postgis), I am able to produce a result that looks like this: [image: bad result].

As you can see, `ST_AddMeasure()` and `ST_LocateAlong()` don't seem to treat the geometry spherically, which results in many points that sit on the South Pole. A point was even added on the clip along the date line (left side). Per the documentation of these two functions, only *geometry* can be used.

The code used to generate the polygon and the points can be [found here](https://gist.github.com/jczaplew/796dbf11a69385959eeb), but this is the SQL used to generate the points:

```sql
CREATE TABLE atest AS WITH line AS 
  (SELECT
      id,
      ST_ExteriorRing((ST_Dump(geom)).geom) AS geom
    FROM line_sample_test),
linemeasure AS
    (SELECT
        ST_AddMeasure(line.geom, 0, (ST_Length(line.geom))::int) AS linem,
    generate_series(0, (ST_Length(line.geom))::int, 10) AS i
FROM line),

geometries AS (
    SELECT
        i,
        ST_LocateAlong(linem, i) AS geom 
    FROM linemeasure)

SELECT
    * from geometries;
```

How can I generate points at every 1000 Km along this coastline?

Comment: Have you tried ST_Segmentize? It also can only work on geometries, but at least seems like a quicker way to generate the points. Anyway, why not just remove points at the pole? It looks more like a side effect of the used projection than a bug.

Comment: From your picture, it looks like you have your geometry in EPSG:4326.  Antarctica is better suited to a polar stereographic projection such as EPSG:3031.  Even then, it looks like you might need to deal with a cut-line to the pole and back, along the Date Line.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in one of the comments, I would first transform the input geometry to a polar stereographic projection.

Addditionally, you'll want to use `ST_Buffer` on it (with an amount of `0`) to get rid of the resulting cut line.

So this would get your desired result:

```
-- ST_Transform(geom,3031) reprojects to south polar stereographic,
-- in meters.  ST_Buffer(...) doesn't change the shape, but removes
-- the cut line to the pole (at 180 degrees).
WITH line AS (
    SELECT ST_ExteriorRing(
        ST_Buffer(ST_Transform(geom, 3031), 0)
    ) AS geom
    FROM line_sample_test
),

-- This just generates a table of numbers.  In this case, from 0
-- to the geometry length, counting by 1,000,000 (1000 km).
linemeasure AS (
    SELECT generate_series(0, ST_Length(geom)::int, 1000000) AS i
    FROM line
),

-- Convert those values to a fraction of the overall length (for
-- use as input to ST_LineInterpolatePoint)
linefraction AS (
    SELECT i / ST_Length(geom) AS fraction
    FROM line, linemeasure
),

-- Do the interpolation
geometries AS (
    SELECT ST_LineInterpolatePoint(l.geom, lf.fraction) AS geom
    FROM linefraction lf, line l
),

-- Convert back to EPSG:4326 (i.e. lat/lon coords)
geometries_4326 AS (
    SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 4326) AS geom FROM geometries
)
SELECT * FROM geometries_4326
```

Note that this query does assume that there's only one row in the `line_sample_test` table, so tweak as necessary for your real input data.

Comment: I didn't know the `ST_Buffer(geom, 0)` trick to eliminate the cut-line - that's useful!