# Return nodes along portions of edges with pgrouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, isochrone

I have been experimenting with generating isochrones with pgrouting using osm data. So far, I have been able to generate isochrone polygons by getting the concave hull of the nodes returned from the pgr_drivingdistance function. Here is a sample query to generate 10 minute (0.166667 hr) isochrone from node 46397, assuming a speed of 5km/h :

```
SELECT 1 AS id, st_concavehull(st_union(t.the_geom), 0.95)
FROM
(SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, pt.the_geom AS the_geom
  FROM pgr_drivingdistance(
    'SELECT id, source, target, (km/5) as cost FROM at_2po_4pgr',
    46397, 0.166667, FALSE, FALSE
  ) AS di
  JOIN at_2po_4pgr_vertices_pgr pt
  ON di.id1 = pt.id) t
```

Which yields the following isochrone :

[image: 10 min isochrone at 5kmh from node 46397]

I would like to know if it is possible to calculate an isochrone 
while considering the possibility of reaching points along a portion of each edge? This would be especially useful in cases where network edges are very long. For example, the pgr_drivingdistance function would return a point 50% along an edge, if only half of the edge could be traversed.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up solving this problem with the following function:

[networkreachpartial](https://github.com/Brent-Edwards/networkReach/tree/patch-1)

Here is an example which generates a 10 minute (0.166667 hr) isochrone from node 46397, assuming a speed of 5km/h:

```
CREATE TABLE networkreachpartial_node_46397_walk_5kph
AS
(SELECT 1 as id, ST_ConcaveHull(st_union(t.geom), 1)
FROM
(select *
from networkreachpartial2('at_2po_4pgr', 'cost_walk_5kph', 'geom_way', array[46397], 0.166667)) t)
```